# my webpage is loading images using flask server

Tags: html, image, flask, server

I am not able to load the images on a web page even they are in a static folder.

I also tried for giving the path of the image but was not able to load

```
<img class="w3-image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='architect.jpg') }}" alt="Architecture" width="1500" height="800">
```

python code :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello_name():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `architect.jpg` image file need to be placed in static folder on the same directly as the main python code to make the file accessible via index.html.
For debugging purpose, you can view file source of the webpage and see what src location `<img>` tag is displaying.

Comment: Thankyou ,it's working